# How to go back to CTRL+ALT+DELETE logon page if the custom credential provider fails to do any authentication?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, winlogon, credential-providers

I have enabled <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> secure attention sequence (SAS) for windows logon using local security policy. (secpol.msc , Security Settings->Local Policies->Security Options->Interactive Logon: Do not require <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> -> Disabled )

Currently the machine is using a facial based custom credential provider for login in Windows 10. In the current setup if the custom credential provider fails during authentication, it falls back to normal windows based logon (Password / Pin).

I have disabled the password, pin based mechanism through the group policy ( gpedit.msc, Computer Configuration ->Administrative Templates->System->Logon , Exclude Credential Providers ). This works fine as password and pin cannot be used for authentication. But the login page is still displayed.

How to always go back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> logon page if the custom credential provider fails to do any authentication so that the user can retry ?

Is it possible to Control through group policy? Do I have to manage through the credential provider source so the fallback always goes back <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> page.

Additional Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc780332(v=ws.10)

Ref section - Winlogon Desktop Dialog Boxes:

In other words it is about switching from "Log On to Windows" desktop "Welcome to Windows" desktop automatically.

Additional Info on the flow:

When Winlogon.exe detects the SAS (Ctrl+Alt+Del), it launches this LogonUI.exe process,which initializes our custom credential provider.

In the normal use case , when our credential provider succeeds , user enters his credentials and the LogonUI.exe process terminates.

Now in the second case, when our custom credential provider fails, desktop becomes blank or if fast user switching is enabled, it displays the switch user button.

In the correct use case , I have to fallback to SAS (Ctrl+Alt+Del)

Comment: Did you create this "facial based custom credential provider for login"? Do you have source code? If negative then I'm afraid this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Your question is not about programming.

Comment: Yes  we have created the facial based custom credential provider. It is Based on this sample -  https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/tree/master/security/credentialproviders/samplehardwareeventcredentialprovider

Comment: Authentication status checked in HRESULT CSampleProvider::SetUsageScenario( __in CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO cpus, __in DWORD dwFlags ).  If it is successful, it triggers the login, if it fails,go back to the default Windows Welcome Screen and initiate the SAS to restart the authentication

Answer (score 1):

```
*pcpgsr = CPGSR_RETURN_NO_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED;
return hr; // return to LogonUI
```

**CPGSR_RETURN_NO_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED** will return from your module to windows system without accepting your security structure. Also use unadvise to cleanup while returning from Serialization call.

Answer (score 0):

Do you solve your issue?

I think in the new scenario of credential providers (versus GINA) it is impossible to control this behaviour.

If <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> is enabled there is no **legal** way to eliminate and/or simulate this secure attention sequence. Have a look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51747455/3868464).